# How to get only date/month part from a date in postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Hello All**
I have a table in my pg admin database.There is an **employee** table in this table.Having the field:-
1)name
2)date_of_birth

Now the scenario is that I want to know the birth day for current date and upcoming 20 days 
For example if current date is 28-Jan-2013 then

```
1)from_date=28-Jan-2013
2)to_date=16-feb-2013
```

I want to select  all the records from the table for which the 
 **date_of_birth**

```
lies between 28-Jan and 16-feb
```

Comment: Is important to you that the year was hide?

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   bdaytable
WHERE  bdate >= '2013-01-28'::DATE
AND    bdate <= '2013-02-16'::DATE;
```

You may also try [`overlaps`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM bdaytable
WHERE (bdate, bdate) 
OVERLAPS ('2013-01-28'::DATE, '2013-02-16'::DATE);
```

[with `extract`, `month`, `day`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

```
SELECT *
FROM   bdaytable
WHERE  Extract(month from bdate) >= Extract(month from '2013-01-28'::DATE)
AND    Extract(month from bdate) <= Extract(month from '2013-02-16'::DATE)
AND    Extract(day from bdate) >= Extract(day from '2013-01-28'::DATE)
AND    Extract(day from bdate) <= Extract(day from '2013-02-16'::DATE);
```

Incorporating `Now()` and `interval` to make the query dynamic with current date:

```
SELECT *
FROM   bdaytable
WHERE  Extract(month from bdate) >= Extract(month from Now())
AND    Extract(month from bdate) <= Extract(month from Now() + Interval '20 day')
AND    Extract(day from bdate) >= Extract(day from Now())
AND    Extract(day from bdate) <= Extract(day from Now() + Interval '20 day');
```

Comment: Thanks dear.But in my case year doesn't matter I want to consider only date and month

Comment: Try with the edit please :), it's ugly with too many `extracts`, but should work.

Comment: I think conditions are not used properly

Comment: Absolutely , good catch, let me know if it's working for you, keen to know ;)

Comment: Another way to do this - `(bdate - date_trunc('year',bdate)) BETWEEN (now() - date_trunc('year',now())) AND (now() - date_trunc('year',now()) + interval '20 days')`. The idea - to compare intervals from the start of the year.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko feel free to post it or update my answer with your comment.

Comment: This query will include a record with bdate `2013-02-17` because it meets all conditions. Which is wrong

Answer (score 4):

```
select *
from employee
where 
    to_char(date_of_birth, 'MMDD') between 
    to_char(current_date, 'MMDD') and to_char(current_date + 20, 'MMDD')
```

Comment: Will it work, when the current date is close (less than 20 days) to the end of the year?

Comment: Thanks this is working fine.But if the current_date is 20-Nov-2012  and to_date is 15-Jan-2013 and I want the result in this order :-birth day for Nov,birth day for DEC and birth day for Jan .How can I achieve this

Comment: @facebook Don't use this answer. It is wrong as already pointed by Igor

Comment: @Clodoaldo  I have modify this to work for all case.I have made 2 range of dates.For example if the date is 20-Dec-2012.Then Dates are:-20-Dec-2012,31-Dec-2012 AND 1-Jan-2013 to 8-Jan-2013

Comment: @facebook Interesting. Could you please post a new question explaining your solution in detail and then asking for the order problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.  Use `interval`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee
WHERE Date_Of_Birth >= now() AND Date_Of_Birth <= now() + interval '20 day'
```

If you want to get any birth date between these days (and year doesn't matter), then that would be slightly different.

EDIT

If year doesn't matter, while I'm sure there is a better way, this could work.  Basically it's just converting all years to a common year (in this case 2000) -- you could do the same with your input parameter as well.

```
(Date_Of_Birth + (2000-EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date_Of_Birth) || ' years')::interval)
```

Curious what others have used in the past as this is probably not the most efficient.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi,As you mention what if  year doesn't matter.In my case year does'nt matter